# How to set up a Postgres SQL database locally in my computer?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have configured a production postgres sql database.
If I need to do debugging work, I don't want to be interacting with the production database or else that will affect the user base. Instead, I need to create a local environment such that nothing will be changed in the production database during debugging.

I am using Postgres SQL 10 and PGAdmin 4

How can I achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a test environment with docker.

first a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
    db:
        image: postgres:10-alpine
        volumes:
            - ./local_path:/var/lib/postgresql/data
        ports:
            - "8000:5432"
        expose:
            - "5432"

    admin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
```

See the documentation for the docker postgres image on how to set environment variables to define user/password/db name. https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

I'm not too familiar with pgadmin but container has minimal setup options:
https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/

Then you start the containers with `sudo docker-compose up`.

The db container is publishing its port on 8000 on your host machine, so there should be no conflict with the postgres server running on the host.

To connect:

```
psql -h localhost -p 8000 -U postgres
```

The admin page should be available at port 8080 on your host machine.
When you connect the admin to the database in the UI, the hostname is `db` and the port is `5432`

Now that you have a docker container set up, you might also consider using it for production also :)